# Access Windows Disks from Ubuntu LiveCD?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

I'am right now on my `Ubuntu 14.04`. I guess and I have a file on my Windows disks (I have three disks) and when I Click on one of them I have this message

```
Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/ubuntu/5208BE9708BE7995: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda2" "/media/ubuntu/5208BE9708BE7995"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

As I said it's not dual booting with my Windows 10 but it's `LiveCD` and i am running from my USB

Comment: "Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option."

Comment: so I reboot PC , boot windows then shutdown using the shutdown button on Windows then go back to Linux LiveCD ?

Comment: That is the idea, yes. Thing is: this notice is to prevent data loss and you can "fix" this from Ubuntu by removing the hiberfile BUT that would also remove anything from windows that was not saved yet. The 2nd comment had a good explanation on this.

Comment: Yeah i started reading , I will reboot and try the solution of booting and shutdown and let you guys know ! thank you so much.

Comment: Also, you could mount the system 'read-only' (ro) if you just want to copy over files.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to read a Windows disk (a partition formatted as NTFS) that is shut down incorrectly or hibernated, this error comes up.

It is displayed when you try to mount the partition in the live operating system because the filesystem NTFS is best altered by the Windows operating system itself. The easiest thing you can do, is reboot in Windows and let windows clean its own file system.

The answer to the following question may explain in a more precise way why the message is displayed: [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Comment: so I reboot PC , boot windows then shutdown using the shutdown button on Windows then go back to Linux LiveCD ? that should do the trick ?

Comment: @user3597342 I hope you are able to do this. Yes, it should do the trick.